# How to access sites at localhost (for debugging) via IP

Tags: vb.net, ip

I can access `http://localhost:1284/UploadResult.ashx?flag=0` and it works. I am programming in ASP and I need to be able to access the site.

Latter I want to test my android app to access the my local server. So I am going to access my site from a different computer, a smart phone actually.

What should I replace localhost with?

What about if I want to access it via IP so that my network friends can access it?

I think I should use the IP

So I did:

ping computerName

The result is

```
Pinging computerName [fe80::7dc7:e3ae:363c:180f%15] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::7dc7:e3ae:363c:180f%15: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::7dc7:e3ae:363c:180f%15: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::7dc7:e3ae:363c:180f%15: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::7dc7:e3ae:363c:180f%15: time<1ms
```

So how should I access it?

```
http://[fe80::7dc7:e3ae:363c:180f%15]:1284/UploadResult.ashx?flag=0
```

doesn't work.

If I try to access the site from my own computer (not from networked computer) and try

```
http://computername:1284/UploadResult.ashx?flag=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `ping -4 your_host_name` in command prompt

Comment: I did that! Read the question

Comment: u did it without the "-4" key. "-4" should tell system to return the ipv4 address

Comment: Still doesn't work but solve some of the problem. Selected upvoted.